# I want to run an async call in laravel and then return true. RETURN TRUE doesn't have to wait for async call to complete

Tags: php, laravel, webhooks, background-task, shopify-app

Actually, I have created a shopify app and it's uninstall webhook with it. While uninstalling the app, shopify notify me about the uninstall of app so i could do some relevant process. If shopify doesn't get response in 5 seconds then it hit me with other notification which leads to two calls.

In my webhook function i just delete the shop from my database which sometimes take time. Is there anything i can do in laravel so my deletion process run asynchronously. After calling the deletion process which will be async so my next line of code could `return "true"`. My uninstall function is in InstallController.php in given code below.

in App\Jobs. I have created BackgroundJobs.php

```php
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class BackgroundJobs implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $shopId;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($shopId)
    {
        $this->shopId = $shopId;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        DB::table("shops")
            ->where("id", $this->shopId)
            ->delete();
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is a Controller InstallController.php in which "uninstall()" function dispatch queue.

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class InstallController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view("install");
    }

    public function uninstall(Request $request)
    {
        $shop_id = $request->get('shopId');
        // dispatching job
        dispatch(new \App\Jobs\BackgroundJobs($shop_id));
        return "true";
    }
}
```

So how can i `return "true"` and doesn't need to wait for queue to finish ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use job events for execute code after or before complete your job

so you define on boot method in AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    Queue::before(function (BackgroundJobs $event) {
        // $event->connectionName
        // $event->job
        // $event->job->payload()
    });

    Queue::after(function (BackgroundJobs $event) {
        // $event->connectionName
        // $event->job
        // $event->job->payload()
    });
}
```

for more details please check official document

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#job-events

Comment: In before section, i can just simply right `return true` which will lead this job to async? On background it'll do the rest job ?